# Spring Boot doesn't work when I add sql script

Tags: sql-server, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a simple Restfull app. It works. But, when I add .sql files - the app doesn't work. 
I add schema.sql

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;

CREATE TABLE country (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
  county_name CHAR (30) NOT NULL UNIQUE );

CREATE TABLE city (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
  city_name CHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  country_id INTEGER REFERENCES country,
  UNIQUE (city_name, country_id));

CREATE TABLE street (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  street_name CHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  city_id INTEGER REFERENCES city,
  building_number CHAR(10),
  UNIQUE (street_name, city_id));
```

and data.sql

```
INSERT INTO country (county_name) VALUES ('Ukraine');
INSERT INTO country (county_name) VALUES ('France');
INSERT INTO country (county_name) VALUES ('Italy');
INSERT INTO country (county_name) VALUES ('German');
INSERT INTO country (county_name) VALUES ('England');
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ubr
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1
server.port=8080
```

After first run - it hasn't an error, but after second run I have [a stacktrace with many exeptions](http://pastebin.ca/3660041). What I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing two different features.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` operates when you want Hibernate to automatically update the schema.

`schema.sql` and `data.sql` management is a Spring Boot feature. The [doc is pretty explicit about JPA usage](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc)

> If you want to use the schema.sql initialization in a JPA app (with Hibernate) then ddl-auto=create-drop will lead to errors if Hibernate tries to create the same tables. To avoid those errors set ddl-auto explicitly to "" (preferable) or "none". Whether or not you use ddl-auto=create-drop you can always use data.sql to initialize new data.

Comment: I changed my .properties:
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`; 
`spring.datasourse.data=/resources/data.sql`
`spring.datasourse.schema=/resources/schema.sql`;
`spring.datasource.continueOnError=true` and it works. All I did right or something wrong?